# How do I render a WPF window into a DirectX buffer?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, directx, rendering

I would like to render a WPF window into my own buffer and add that to my render loop, render into my own scene, manipulate it, etc.

Is there a built-in way to capture a WPF window's underlying DirectX buffer/swapchain?

Comment: This opposite scenario is more common. See [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPFDXInterop)

Comment: Yes it is. But that's easy

Comment: I don't think there's anyway to get WPF's internal swapchain, but you can capture the whole WPF application's window (or any window that allows this, not cloaked, not protected, etc.) from the screen. If running off Windows 8+, you can use IDXGIOutputDuplication for that.

Comment: This came up early, all the way back in 2006.  Never addressed, BitmapRenderTarget can't make anybody happy.  It was [eventually implemented](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2013/11/19/whats-new-for-xaml-and-directx-interop-in-windows-8-1/) but without any regard for marrying this to Milcore.  There is a [hardy soul](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/438/How-to-get-access-to-WPF-s-internal-Direct3D-guts.aspx) that hacked it, but looks only interesting to gucci bag shoppers.

Comment: @HansPassant So, if I usea SwapChainPanel, with an empty SwapChange, it will render the XAML ontop of my buffer?

Comment: Made for UWP, not WPF.  The odds that Milcore will ever get replaced are very slim.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, but it's fairly similar, I could run UWP on Windows 10. But does it render the XAML over the Provided swapchain ?

Comment: @HansPassant Does UWP still use Milcore under the hood?

Comment: Nope, Milcore is legacy.  The UWP compositing engine is much more flexible, it has [an api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition).

Comment: @HansPassant That's really interesting thank you. Does Windows.Ui.Composition communicate to DirectX determining version based on system?

Answer (score 4):

**Possible but not easy.**

There is two great articles I found when trying to achieve this both by Jeremiah Morrill.

[A Critical Deep Dive into the WPF Rendering System](https://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2011/02/14/a-critical-deep-dive-into-the-wpf-rendering-system/)

[How to get access to WPF’s internal Direct3D guts](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/438/How-to-get-access-to-WPF-s-internal-Direct3D-guts.aspx)

Jeremiah uses a `Dynamic Link Library (DLL)` written in C++ which hooks DirectX functions and exports `initialise` function in which C# calls.

**This still does not stop you using [Easyhook](https://easyhook.github.io/) and doing it in C# instead of Jeremiahs way.**

When doing this myself this was my flow:

1. Hook DirectX 9/10/11 (EndScene, Present)..
2. Callback in .NET domain
   and marshal buffer data using [PInvoke](https://pinvoke.net/)
3. Manipulate buffer return
   manipulated buffer back to C++ library
4. Display the final image buffer to
   screen i.e WPF...

My experience: there is a compromise on speed but I believe with optimisation could be viable solution.

**Another Solution**
<s>You could EAT hook `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` which is an export from `d3d11.dll`.</s> This won't work since WPF uses DirectX 9 under the hood.

### Update:

After reversing WPF over the weekend I found unmanaged `wpfgfx.dll` which contains `milcore` which is a wrapper around DirectX 9 still to this date. You can see this in the below diagram of WPF Architecture.

[image: WPF Architecture]

Inside the module `wpfgfx.dll` it contains MILCore DirectX wrapper. More about [WPF Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-architecture)